# Subsonic3 & GUIDs

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, guid

I have a table with a PrimaryKey that is set as uniqueidentifier (GUID) and it's autopopulated using the newsequentialid() function from sql server 2008...  When I insert a row manually, everything works as normal.  But when I insert the record using the subsonic class and the repository the GUID column defaults to all zero's and the database will enter that value.  I need it to NOT do this and use the default value of the column... anyone else able to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in 2.0.2 for SQL 2005 - I'm wondering if there's an issue with SQL 2008. What version are you using? I'm thinking this might not have been covered in 3.x just yet.

Comment: I am using a Version of SS3 with the T4 templates...  Can't remember which SVN revision though.  For now, I'm generating a COMB to get around the issue, but I would like to see it work normally.  Maybe I will get the latest from the SVN and see if the problem is still there - that way we can know exactly which version I am using.